# OFDM symbols terminology explanation

Tags: digital-communications, frequency-spectrum, radio, software-defined-radio

I've already read and understand what does OFDM mean and what does it stand for and why we use it in our wireless technology today.
My question that I didn't understand is what does it mean number of "OFDM symbol per frame is 1 or two or 3 ..whatever"?
to clear more, lets assume I have pattern of data to transmit : [0 1 0] , and at each frame number of OFDM symbols is 2.
so what does it mean? is it mean the following claim on the data:
the data [0 1 0] will be stored in three frames and at each frame there's two OFDM symbols? so for is instance

- 0 is stored in frame and it has two OFDM symbols
- 1 is stored in frame and it has two OFDM symbols
- 0 is stored in frame and it has two OFDM symbols

So if that's true , what does it mean that 0 have two OFDM symbols? I need to understand what does it mean that certain frame has N OFDM symbols.

Appreciated for any help.

Comment: Are you studying a specific waveform like LTE or something? I ask because you are talking about frame and I don't think OFDM on its own has a notion of frame but rather that would be a part of a specific waveform protocol

Comment: Hm, your statements don't add up. if you have three numbers or bits to transmit, that's probably less than one OFDM *symbol* worth of date. You sure you fully understood OFDM?

Comment: Yes Im talking about LTE , mobile communication.

Comment: @MarcusMüller maybe not ;) I mean I understand OFDM , could you in simple words explain what it mean for instance a frame / resource block has 3 OFDM symbols? thanks alot

Comment: Any help guys? thanks alot.

Comment: @Maher it simply means that three consecutive OFDM symbols make up a frame! An OFDM symbol, however, doesn't encode "0" or "1"; it is made up of the many symbols on the many subcarriers.

Comment: Understand .. thanks alot